# Error logs after package-lock.json is generated

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package-lock.json

After installing `babel-cli` package locally on a project.. I started to get error logs when I type `npm list --depth 0` in the command line. It's very annoying.. but I'm not sure if it's casing any other problems.

I've tried to install `babel-cli` and `babel-core` globally. But, nothing really changed. When I type `npm list --depth 0 -g` with the `-g` flag, it returns with a very clean list of my packages.

Here's the logs when I run both commands:

```
$ npm ls --depth 0 -g
C:\Users\YahiaRefaiea\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- babel-cli@6.26.0
+-- babel-core@6.26.0
+-- grunt-cli@1.2.0
+-- gulp-cli@1.4.0
`-- npm@5.6.0
```

And:

```
$ npm ls --depth 0
test@1.0.0 C:\Dropbox\Projects\In Progress\test
+-- babel-cli@6.26.0
+-- babel-core@6.26.0
+-- babel-preset-env@1.6.1
`-- express@4.16.2

npm ERR! missing: hawk@3.1.3, required by node-pre-gyp@0.6.39
npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by node-pre-gyp@0.6.39
npm ERR! missing: rimraf@2.6.1, required by node-pre-gyp@0.6.39
npm ERR! missing: tar@2.2.1, required by node-pre-gyp@0.6.39
npm ERR! missing: boom@2.10.1, required by hawk@3.1.3
npm ERR! missing: cryptiles@2.0.5, required by hawk@3.1.3
npm ERR! missing: hoek@2.16.3, required by hawk@3.1.3
npm ERR! missing: sntp@1.0.9, required by hawk@3.1.3
npm ERR! missing: hoek@2.16.3, required by boom@2.10.1
npm ERR! missing: boom@2.10.1, required by cryptiles@2.0.5
npm ERR! missing: hoek@2.16.3, required by sntp@1.0.9
npm ERR! missing: minimist@0.0.8, required by mkdirp@0.5.1
npm ERR! missing: console-control-strings@1.1.0, required by npmlog@4.1.0
npm ERR! missing: readable-stream@2.2.9, required by are-we-there-yet@1.1.4
npm ERR! missing: console-control-strings@1.1.0, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: string-width@1.0.2, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: code-point-at@1.1.0, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: number-is-nan@1.0.1, required by is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0
npm ERR! missing: ansi-regex@2.1.1, required by strip-ansi@3.0.1
npm ERR! missing: string-width@1.0.2, required by wide-align@1.1.2
npm ERR! missing: combined-stream@1.0.5, required by request@2.81.0
npm ERR! missing: hawk@3.1.3, required by request@2.81.0
npm ERR! missing: mime-types@2.1.15, required by request@2.81.0
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.0.1, required by request@2.81.0
npm ERR! missing: delayed-stream@1.0.0, required by combined-stream@1.0.5
npm ERR! missing: combined-stream@1.0.5, required by form-data@2.1.4
npm ERR! missing: mime-types@2.1.15, required by form-data@2.1.4
npm ERR! missing: extsprintf@1.0.2, required by jsprim@1.4.0
npm ERR! missing: extsprintf@1.0.2, required by verror@1.3.6
npm ERR! missing: mime-db@1.27.0, required by mime-types@2.1.15
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.0.1, required by tunnel-agent@0.6.0
npm ERR! missing: glob@7.1.2, required by rimraf@2.6.1
npm ERR! missing: fs.realpath@1.0.0, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: inflight@1.0.6, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: path-is-absolute@1.0.1, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by inflight@1.0.6
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by inflight@1.0.6
npm ERR! missing: brace-expansion@1.1.7, required by minimatch@3.0.4
npm ERR! missing: balanced-match@0.4.2, required by brace-expansion@1.1.7
npm ERR! missing: concat-map@0.0.1, required by brace-expansion@1.1.7
npm ERR! missing: block-stream@0.0.9, required by tar@2.2.1
npm ERR! missing: fstream@1.0.11, required by tar@2.2.1
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by tar@2.2.1
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by block-stream@0.0.9
npm ERR! missing: graceful-fs@4.1.11, required by fstream@1.0.11
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by fstream@1.0.11
npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by fstream@1.0.11
npm ERR! missing: rimraf@2.6.1, required by fstream@1.0.11
npm ERR! missing: fstream@1.0.11, required by tar-pack@3.4.0
npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by tar-pack@3.4.0
npm ERR! missing: readable-stream@2.2.9, required by tar-pack@3.4.0
npm ERR! missing: rimraf@2.6.1, required by tar-pack@3.4.0
npm ERR! missing: tar@2.2.1, required by tar-pack@3.4.0
npm ERR! missing: fstream@1.0.11, required by fstream-ignore@1.0.5
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by fstream-ignore@1.0.5
npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by fstream-ignore@1.0.5
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by once@1.4.0
npm ERR! missing: buffer-shims@1.0.0, required by readable-stream@2.2.9
npm ERR! missing: core-util-is@1.0.2, required by readable-stream@2.2.9
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@2.2.9
npm ERR! missing: isarray@1.0.0, required by readable-stream@2.2.9
npm ERR! missing: process-nextick-args@1.0.7, required by readable-stream@2.2.9
npm ERR! missing: string_decoder@1.0.1, required by readable-stream@2.2.9
npm ERR! missing: util-deprecate@1.0.2, required by readable-stream@2.2.9
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.0.1, required by string_decoder@1.0.1
```

Any idea on how to fix this? or at least make it a bit less noisy?

I really appreciate your help guys!

**Update**

I've also tried to `prune` the packages but It still the same.. Here's the logs:

```
$ npm prune
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

up to date in 10.467s
```

I'm running on **Windows 10** with `npm@5.6.0` and `node@v8.9.1`

**Another update**

I found that the problem exactly comes from the `package-lock.json` file which generated everytime we run `npm install something`. I deleted the file after installing all my packages and when I run `npm ls --depth 0` it becomes very clean only with my packages names.
But as I know, It's not good to remove the `package-lock.json` file. right?
Is there any hidden problems I don't know about?

Comment: Do you found a solution? I have the same problem. Here is an issue on github: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19393

Comment: Unfortunately not :( I just removed the package-lock.json file to get it up and running with my application.

Comment: I have same problem, on windows 10 and same dependencie errors

Answer (score 0):

if not using repository

npm config set package-lock false